# Diferencia entre iniciar y iniciarse

Tags: verbo-pronominal

Hoy leí una cita del nuevo presidente de Perú *Pedro Castillo Terrones*:

> Un nuevo tiempo se ha iniciado. Millones de peruanos/as se han alzado
> en defensa de su dignidad y justicia.

La diferencia entre *iniciar* e *iniciarse* (es decir, **un nuevo tiempo se ha iniciado** vs **un nuevo tempo ha iniciado**) es apenas ***énfasis***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Iniciar](https://dle.rae.es/iniciar?m=form)* es un verbo transitivo. **“Un nuevo tiempo ha iniciado”* es una oración gramaticalmente incorrecta. Al añadir *se*, su significado pasa a ser mediopasivo. No se trata exactamente de voz pasiva, aunque se le parezca. Tampoco es reflexivo. *“Un nuevo tiempo se ha iniciado”* significa que un nuevo tiempo ha comenzado “por sí solo”, es decir, por sus propias causas internas. Esta alternancia de *iniciar* es como la de *abrir*, por ejemplo: *“El hombre abrió la puerta” → “La puerta se abrió”*.

*Iniciar* es sinónimo de *comenzar*, pero *comenzar* puede pasar de transitivo a intransitivo sin necesidad de agregar *se*.

Comment: En el contexto del discurso del nuevo presidente peruano, no me parece que él quiso decir que un nuevo tiempo ha comenzado "por sí solo", por sus propias causas internas, sino por el hecho que el ganó las elecciones a la presidencia de Perú y que él será el responsable por grandes cambios en el pais. De todos modos, poderías añadir detalles sobre el mediopasivo?

Comment: No es que el tiempo se haya iniciado por sí sólo, sino que el presidente elige no mencionar su causa (sería inapropiado que dijera "yo he iniciado un nuevo tiempo").

Comment: La voz mediopasiva es similar a la pasiva, pero en vez de haber un agente implícito que realiza la acción, la acción ocurre por causas que se consideran internas al sujeto. Los verbos pronominales como *abrirse, romperse, hundirse* y muchos otros son mediopasivos. En portugués, creo, muchos de estos verbos no usan *se*, pero su significado es mediopasivo cuando son intransitivos.

Comment: Sería inapropiado gramaticalmente o politicamente que él dijera "yo he iniciado un nuevo tiempo"? Me suena arrogante, pero correcto gramaticalmente.

Comment: Nadie aqui ha comentado frases como: El presidente inició la sesión. No entiendo porqué.

Comment: @Alan Evangelista Yo creo que se restringe en el hecho mismo, no en quien eligió o va a ejecutar el mandato, esa relación se hace a partir de la 2da oración. Como indique si se quiere ser más explícito debe usarse el pretérito perfecto para no ser autorreferente, del tipo discurso hablado 'ha sido/iniciado/establecido (+por/debido su/vuestra/propia elección)'. Más que ser arrogante está diciendo que los peruanos eligieron cambiar porque según él al ser de izq van a ser representados y no como antes con gob. de der o una izq. comportándose como de der.

Comment: @Lambie Porque tiene nada que ver con mi questión, comprendo el uso de "iniciar" como verbo transitivo

Comment: @Lambie El presidente inició la sesión/La sesión ha sido iniciada por el presidente, en "La sesión se ha iniciado" por sí misma la frase no me indica que el presidente la haya iniciado.

Comment: @cocteau Hay que mostrar la diferencia de alguna manera. "La diferencia entre iniciar e iniciarse (es decir, un nuevo tiempo se ha iniciado vs un nuevo tempo ha iniciado) es apenas énfasis?)" "Un tiempo" no puede iniciar nada.

Comment: @Lambie En resumen: Iniciar como transitivo debe tener un sujeto en la activa pero para que se pueda omitir al agente en la pasiva se debe agregar el morfema 'se' sí o sí, pero ese 'se' no tiene un vínculo sintáctico con la segunda oración, son autónomas pero no excluyentes. El 'se' no nos dice en quien recae la responsabilidad de iniciar una nueva época. Activa: X inició nueva época||Pasivas: Se inició una nueva época/Se dio inicio a una nueva época/Una nueva epoca se ha iniciado/Se ha iniciado una nueva época/Una nueva época ha sido inicida(sin importar el orden se omite al agente)

Comment: @cocteau No se trata de explicármelo a mi, sino que en las repuestas no se da ningún exemplo. ¿ Crees que yo necesito entenderlo? Ya lo sé. Vuelvo a repetir: **un tiempo no inicia** nada. Una persona inicia algo. Se inicia un tiempo, claro. Además, es igualito en portugués: O presidente iniciou a sessão. As aulas se iniciaram a semana passada.

Comment: @Lambie El que inicia el cambio puede ser un presidente, un movimiento, una elección, etc. El tiempo es algo intangible. El nuevo tiempo es iniciado por el agente.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que entra en la categoría de valor expresivo omitible que ocurre cuando el «se» no es requerido por el verbo pero toma una función sintactica similar a la del complemento indirecto para aportar un nuevo significado en el caso del verbo intr. pronominal. Lo mismo que ocurre en verbos no pronominales para darle otro matiz cuando se construye con la 3ra persona.

- Se inició hace mucho tiempo(It took place a long time ago)
- El usuario que se ha iniciado sesión(Logged-in user)
- Mac se inicia más rápido(Mac starts faster)
- Una vez se ha iniciado el juego(Once the game is started)

https://www.rae.es/dpd/iniciar

P.átono+v.pronominal/Se+v.intrasitivo/Se+v.copulativo/Le(s) -> se +lo(s)/la(s)(pronombres de acusativo)

En mi variedad es «se inició». Tal vez se diría «se ha iniciado» como para evocar algo o declamar, como diciendo habemus o algo por el estilo, pero eso ya sería un caso particular.

Comment: Aportar cuál nuevo significado? El ejemplo 1 no tiene sujeto y el pronombre "se" es usado para representar ese sujeto inexistente, así que creo que no está relacionados con mi ejemplo donde hay un sujeto. Los ejemplos 2 y 3 tienen sujeto, pero me parece que tienen el mismo significado sin el pronombre "se". El ejemplo 4 está en la voz pasiva, así que no aporta un nuevo significado, sino es una alternativa gramatical para la voz activa (con sujeto inexistente en ese caso).

Comment: @AlanEvangelista En el primero 'it' se refiere a un fenómeno de carga de los ferrocarriles y camiones, pensé eras un nativo de inglés tratando de entender en inglés. En 2 como dices tienen el mismo significado, la RAE dice que puede suprimirse el 'se' sin que cambie el significado, pero dice que aporta matices de tipo expletivo. En la última tienes razón lo agregué como ej de pasiva nada más. A mi entender para que se establezca esa relación debe decir '...ha sido iniciado por/...fue iniciada por', el 'se' por si solo no me dice nada, pero tal vez es algo regional.

Comment: Se inició una nueva época. Millones de peruanos/as se alzaron en defensa de su dignidad y justicia[El 'Se' no me indica que los peruano/as iniciaron la nueva época]/Una nueva época ha sido iniciada[por alguien o algo]. Millones de peruanos/as se alzaron en defensa de su dignidad y justicia (En mi variedad)

Comment: El usuario que se ha iniciado sesión/El usuario que haya iniciado la sesión(en mi variedad) || Una vez se ha iniciado el juego/Una vez que se haya iniciado el juego(en mi variedad)

Answer (score 0):

Al anteponer el pronombre **se** a un verbo transitivo, estamos indicando que el sujeto es el paciente de la acción. Es decir, en la oración:

> Un nuevo tiempo **se** ha iniciado

Existe algo o alguien que ha propiciado que *un nuevo tiempo* inicie. Este tipo de construcción es muy usado en la jerga política porque despersonaliza (aunque no completamente) el acto.

Por el contrario, en la oración:

> Un nuevo tiempo inició

No hay nada que implique que el inicio del *nuevo tiempo* haya sido causado por alguien o algo.

Cuando anteponemos **se**, podemos usar la voz activa. También funciona:

> Un nuevo tiempo **se** inició

porque la [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/se?m=form) establece que el verbo debe interpretarse como pasivo.

Otros ejemplos:

> **Se** ofreció una fiesta para recaudar fondos.
> **Se** colocó la primera piedra del nuevo hospital.
> **Se** compró el material de seguridad necesario.

Comment: Entonces "un nuevo tiempo se ha iniciado" (se + pretérito perfecto compuesto) = "un nuevo tiempo fue iniciado" (voz pasiva)?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista. Si, es equivalente. Ahondando más, podríamos decir: “Un nuevo tiempo fue iniciado por millones de peruanos” o “Millones de peruanos iniciaron un nuevo tiempo”.

Comment: Pero también hay iniciar transitivo y sin pasivo.  La sesíon inició a las 10.